# Selecting available Usernames while creating Gmail Account using Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

How to select from available usernames while creating Gmail account using Selenium when the username was chosen is already taken?

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/?pc=topnav-about-en");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("7 Grams");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Cafe");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("GmailAddress")).sendKeys("7gcafe");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

I wanted steps after this: I am looking to select the first suggested username that appears in the available usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium python: 
first we find email input and send keys, when it's wrong we use try to find error message and except new email address with e.g. random int added.
For username similar with another selector.

```
   email = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#GmailAddress")
   email.send_keys("kowalski")
   next_step = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#submitbutton")
   next_step.click()
   try:
       error = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.errormsg")
   except Exception:
       email2 = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#GmailAddress")
       rand = random.randint(1, 10)
       randS = str(rand)
       email2.send_keys("kowalski"+randS)
```

[image: Now in gmail it is no username suggestion]
Now it looks like this.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Could you assist me in writing this in Selenium Java? I am looking to select the first available username that Gmail is suggesting when the username we chose is already taken.

Comment: If you want i can rewrite this code in Java. Please try to to trigger situation with suggesting usernames and make screen of html code.

Comment: WebElement gmailUsername = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#GmailAddress"));
  gmailUsername.sendKeys("abcabc");
  WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#submitbutton"));
  submitButton.click();
  try{
   WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.errormsg"));
   WebElement gmailUsername2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.username-suggestions>a:first-of-type"));
   gmailUsername2.click();
   submitButton.click();
  }
  catch(WebDriverException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: String error = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='errormsg_0_GmailAddress']")).getText();
     if(error.equals("That username is taken. Try another."))
     {
         List<WebElement> available = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username-suggestions']/a"));
      System.out.println("Size "+available.size());
      
      for(int i=1;i<=available.size();i++)
      {
       WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username-suggestions']/a["+i+"]"));
       e.click();
       break;
      }
     }

Comment: I have tried this and is working....Thank you